# Is gossip kind of questions can be asked on this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I wrote and answer the following question in order to share my knowledge, Q&A-style.

[Why did a swimmer wear a swim cap with someone else's name?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/why-swimmer-wore-swim-cap-with-someone-else-name/1245#1245)

I also wrote it because a lot of people asked me about this weird situation.
I even heard some broadcasters wondering about this..

So my question is if you think those kind of question belongs to this site? They have a tone of gossip so I am not really sure.

From one hand it's very interesting because this gossip satisfies the curiosity of Sport consumers and adds volume to our site,
From the other hand this is pure gossip.

What do you think??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question didn't strike me as "gossip." However, this is similar to asking why Chad Johnson (once [Chad Ochocinco](http://news.blogs.cnn.com/2012/07/24/ochocinco-becomes-johnson-again/)) had ["Ocho Cinco"](http://www.getsportsinfo.com/image.axd?picture=Ocho+Cinco.jpg) on the nameplate on his NFL jersey. I can see such an occurence addressed by a rule in a rulebook, and hence, a valid question for [Sports SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) in my opinion.

Comment: Can you reopen the question?

Comment: Please flag the question with your request.