# How do we handle this subset of "how to" questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Several questions have been asked in a subset of "how-to" such that:

- [How to enter in 2016 Olympics?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/how-to-enter-in-2016-olympics)
- [How does one become a DDCA umpire?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3112/how-does-one-become-a-ddca-umpire)

Related information on a historic meta post:

- [Range of localization for Sports questions](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/range-of-localization-for-sports-questions)

**How do we handle this subset of "how to" questions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me, like you said, this it too broad. Not only that, but there are probably official channels that should be referenced when learning "how-to" that are maintained by governing bodies and I'd rather not be handing out advice or answers that could become outdated when the official "how-to" changes.

Comment: This becomes case-by-case, but it sounds like you're saying to direct others to official sources. International -> National -> Regional -> State -> Local.

Comment: You are correct. "How-to" in those cases can end up changing and I don't think portraying ourselves (or our answers) as any kind of source of official reference would be very wise long-term.

Answer (score 1):

In short, my opinion on this subset of "how to" questions: rarely useful, too broad, and tends to lean toward personal recommendation vs. benefitting the community.

[Recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are not generally encouraged. Also, for this subset of "how to" questions, effort (in the form of research, what have you tried?, etc.) would be complimentary information toward helping the user out.