# Location specific questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

When I go to new location such as London and Oslo, the first thing is: where are the gyms with certain kind of facility like good for canonical training? Where are the bouldering places? Where can you go dancing Waltz? And so on. Are location-specific questions allowed on this site?

Answer (score 4):

The questions you present would be off-topic because they are [research requests](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For example:

> Where are the nearest CrossFit gym(s) in [enter city here]?
>
> Where can I rock-climb near [enter city here]?

To further nitpick, the content of your questions are more specific to fitness and dance rather than sports.

In regards of location-specificity, this has been discussed before [here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/range-of-localization-for-sports-questions) with a favorable viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it to be off-topic, for reasons of it being opinion based and not directly related to sports.

We had such an instance on Web Applications as well. Somebody wanted to know where to find the best coffee: [find best coffee](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37499/29140).

Come to think of it, I don't think it's on topic across all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: How are the questions opinion-based? A question in the form "Where can you do activity X in city Y?" would return a list of [equally valid answers](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @edmastermind29 I'm referring to a good canonical training.

Comment: That's true. In that case, I would drop the adjective to not represent one's opinion when asking a question.